# Symfony Maker Bundle - How to update doctrine entity properties?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Used Maker Bundle to create an entity for doctrine.

In doing so I created a property I decided I did not want:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $weight;
```

I deleted the `weight` property and the get and set methods.

```
public function getWeight(): ?int
{
    return $this->weight;
}

public function setWeight(?int $weight): self
{
    $this->weight = $weight;

    return $this;
}
```

But, when I run Maker Bundle again to update the entity and add other new properties, the weight property and methods return.

How can I **update** and/or **remove** a property of an entity with either a MakerBundle command or directly editing the class?

Comment: Do you update database schema?

Comment: Not yet, I have only created the entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are caching doctrine metadata in redis or apcu or ... so you will need to clear doctrine metadata cache after you removed the property and its getter and setter:

`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`